# immutablejs mergeIn OrderedMap returns Map if no key exists

Tags: immutable.js

I am trying to create an object, where if neccessary, keys in that object when created are created as OrderedMaps.

ie.

```
OrderedMap().setIn(['users','subusers'], OrderedMap())
```

What I want

```
OrderedMap->users->OrderedMap()->subusers->OrderedMap()
```

What I actually get

```
OrderedMap->users->Map()->subusers->OrderedMap()
```

Is there any simple way to get an OrderedMap with only OrderedMaps in it?

Comment: Would be a great feature! You should create an issue against Immutable.js on GitHub for this.

Comment: I have observed the same behavior with `OrderedMap.updateIn( keyPath, updater)` and `OrderedMap.mergeIn( keyPath, ...iterables)` and would have the same request: how to have these methods create `OrderedMap` structures, rather than `Map`, at any key of keyPath that does not exist? –so that every part of the structure retains order.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, all `whateverIn` functions end in `updateIn`, which uses `emptyMap()` as its notSetValue. I guess that adding a reviver function similar to Immutable's [fromJS](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/fromJS) would be a good idea and might be accepted as Issue/Pull Request.

Note that when you construct full trees from scratch, you might just want to use fromJS with a custom reviver. Here is a copy of the example from the ImmutableJS doc:

```
const { fromJS, isKeyed } = require('immutable@4.0.0-rc.9')
fromJS({ a: {b: [10, 20, 30]}, c: 40}, function (key, value, path) {
  console.log(key, value, path)
  return isKeyed(value) ? value.toOrderedMap() : value.toList()
})
```

Below is an updater function which uses OrderedMap instead.

```js
let map = Immutable.OrderedMap({key0:Immutable.OrderedMap()}).setIn(['key0','key1', 'key2', 'key3'], 'banana');

function check(what, name) {
  console.log('verify map using', name);
  let entry = what.entrySeq().first();

  while(entry) {
    if (Immutable.isImmutable(entry[1])) {
      console.log(`${entry[0]} is ${Immutable.isOrdered(entry[1]) ? '' : 'un'}ordered`);
      entry = entry[1].entrySeq().first();
    } else {
      console.log(`${entry[0]} = ${entry[1]}` );
      entry = null;
    }
  }
}

check(map, 'setIn');


function orderedUpdateIn(what, path, value) {
  if (what.has(path)) {
    return what.setIn(path, value);
  }
  
  let missingPath = [], existingPath = [];
  let pathMap = what;
  
  // figure out what part is missing
  for (let i = 0;i < path.length; i++) {
    pathMap = pathMap.get(path[i]);
    if (!pathMap) {
      missingPath = path.slice(i);
      existingPath = path.slice(0,i);
      break;
    }
  }
  
  // build missing part
  let valueToSet = Immutable.OrderedMap({ 
    [missingPath[missingPath.length - 1]]: value
  });
  
  for (let i = missingPath.length - 1;i >= 0; i--) {
    valueToSet = Immutable.OrderedMap({
      [missingPath[i]]: valueToSet
    });
  }

  return map.setIn(existingPath, valueToSet);
}

map = orderedUpdateIn(Immutable.OrderedMap({key0:Immutable.OrderedMap()}), ['key0','key1', 'key2', 'key3'], 'banana');
check(map, 'updateIn');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/4.0.0-rc.12/immutable.js"></script>
```